# Theory: Axios Calls (Specifically for VueJS)

Tags: vue.js

On component `mount()`, Axios fetches information from the back end. On a production site, where the user is going back and forth between routes it would be inefficient to make the same call again and again when the data is already in `state`.

How do the pros design their VueJS apps so that unnecessary Axios calls are not made?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is central to your application and being stored in Vuex (assuming that's what you mean by *"state"*), why not just load it where you initialise your store?

```js
// store.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'wherever'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    centralData: {}
  },
  mutations: {
    setCentralData (state, centralData) {
      state.centralData = centralData
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async loadCentralData ({ commit }) {
      const { data } = await axios.get('/backend')
      commit('setCentralData', data)
    }
  }
}

// initialise
export const init = store.dispatch('loadCentralData')

export default store
```

---

If you need to wait for the dispatch to complete before (for example) mounting your root `Vue` instance, you can use the `init` promise

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import router from 'path/to/router'
import store, { init } from 'path/to/store'

init.then(() => {
  new Vue({
    store,
    router,
    // etc
  }).$mount('#app')
})
```

You can import and use the `init` promise anywhere in order to wait for the data to load.