# VueJS Switching routes causing memory leak?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have run into an issue switching between pages in my Vue app. The first thing my app does upon loading the Home route is sending an api request to my server, returning a payload needed for my app to operate. This normally works fine, but I've noticed if I switch between my About or Contact routes and back to Home in quick succession, it causes my app to halt and crash.

I can only assume this is a memory leak because my getPayload function is being called every time the Home route is switched to. I don't understand why this is happening... When switching routes Vue should be destroying the component & freeing the memory it was using right? If this isn't the case, how can I make it free the memory & stop the API call?

---

WHAT I'VE TRIED:

- Storing a isFetching bool in app state to prevent getPayload() from sending duplicate requests to API if it's set to true

This did not work because when switching routes, the Home component gets destroyed and resets state and when going back to Home, it defaults the bool to false again. I've also tried storing the bool in localstorage instead of app state, however this also fails because the bool never gets set back to false so going back to Home just doesn't load anything after the first switch.

- Disabling the links to About or Contact until the API request finishes

This obviously works but doesn't feel like a real solution, just a hacky fix.

- Forcing page reload when switching to Home route

This works because About and Contact are static content and no state needs to be held between route        changes. However like the "fix" above, it's hacky and I know there has to be a better way. This is what I'm currently using as the solution but it feels very amateur.. Would appreciate any other ideas or advice!

Comment: You could try performing your API call just once in `main.js` or something like that. See here for an example. [How to load all server side data on initial vue.js / vue-router load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572974/how-to-load-all-server-side-data-on-initial-vue-js-vue-router-load)

Comment: Here's another example. [Theory: Axios Calls (Specifically for VueJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62337294/theory-axios-calls-specifically-for-vuejs)

Comment: Appreciate your responses Phil, I'll try to refactor it that way and see how it works!